# How to drag & drop select -option element with Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, html-select

I have recently tried to drag option box content in select element. It seems that ca not be done - drag doesn't fire at all.
I consider redesign this element totally that it will act & look as Select. Other option with jQuery is described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
In my case it must be done with Vanilla.JS.
I can of course back-engineer the above code, however maybe someone knows other working solution?

Answer (score 0):

Make the element you wish to drag absolute and place it above the rest of the content using `z-index`. Then get the `x` and `y` coordinates of the element. Move the element directly into the body, center the element on pointer. Add an event listener for `mousemove` using a function to center the element at the page `x`/`y` coords. Function to drop element when you release the mouse button `.onmouseup`, this would remove all event listeners relevant to the moving of the element.

**NOTE:** *This is very basic, more code would have to be used to determine page constraints in case user drags element out of the page bounding.*

```js
let drag = document.getElementById('draggableSpan');

drag.onmousedown = function(event) {
  // make element absolute and place it on top with z-index
  drag.style.position = 'absolute';
  drag.style.zIndex = 1000;
  
  let shiftX = event.clientX - drag.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  let shiftY = event.clientY - drag.getBoundingClientRect().top;

  // move it out of any current parents directly into body
  // to make it positioned relative to the body
  document.body.append(drag);

  // function that centers the element at (pageX, pageY) coordinates
  function moveTo(pageX, pageY) {
    drag.style.left = pageX - shiftX + 'px';
    drag.style.top = pageY - shiftY + 'px';
  }

  // move the absolutely positioned element under the pointer
  moveTo(event.pageX, event.pageY);

  function onMouseMove(event) {
    moveTo(event.pageX, event.pageY);
  }

  // move the element on mousemove with event  listener
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);

  // drop the element on the page by removing eventlisteners that 
  // are relavent to the moving of the element
  drag.onmouseup = function() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    drag.onmouseup = null;
  };

};
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <span id='draggableSpan'>
      draggable
  </span>
</div>
```